# Conversion to HEVC using FFmpeg produces video s incompatible with Keynote, but Handbrake works

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.265, keynote

I have a video
( https://www.dropbox.com/s/01rg7rgarqfruy3/Spore%20-%20Assymetrical%20Creatures%2C%20excerpt.mov?dl=0 )
that I want to convert to HEVC (H265).

When I convert it using Handbrake, it produces an output video that I can then include in a presentation in Keynote.

When I convert it using ffmpeg on the command line myself, then the output cannot be included in a Keynote presentation;
the error message I get is "Operation could not be completed".
The ffmpeg version plays fine in Quicktime Player, though.
I have already googled, but could not find a solution to the mystery.
Also, I have already looked at Handbrake's Activity Log, but could not find a substantial difference .
I have already tried to change some of the options and parameters I usually use for running ffmpeg, to no avail.

Question is: how do I have to run ffmpeg, which options should I use, so that the output can always be included in Keynote?

Note that some ffmpeg output videos can be inserted in Keynote.
I know that I could, of course, always use Handbrake to manually convert the videos, but I'd rather use ffmpeg on the command line so that I can convert lots of my videos in batch.

*Steps to reproduce the problem:*

Convert this video 
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/01rg7rgarqfruy3/Spore%20-%20Assymetrical%20Creatures%2C%20excerpt.mov?dl=0
using Handbrake using the H265 codec.

Convert it also using ffmpeg. My command line is:
`/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -hide_banner -nostats -nostdin -i "Spore - Assymetrical Creatures, excerpt copy.mov" -map 0 -map -0:v:1 -c:s copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -dn -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -c:a aac -b:a 128k -filter:v crop=in_w-mod(in_w\,2):in_h-mod(in_h\,2) -codec:v hevc -tag:v hvc1 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -preset faster -crf 25 -x265-params me=umh:subme=5:ref=4:aq-mode=2:aq-strength=1.0:psy-rd=2.0:psy-rdoq=1.0:rd=6:profile=main:log-level=2 -ignore_unknown -f mp4 "Spore - Assymetrical Creatures, excerpt copy.h265.mp4_converting"`

Go to Keynote / Insert / Choose .. , select the video (either the Handbrake or the ffmpeg version).

My HandBrake version (e.g., 1.0.0):
Version 1.2.0 (2018122200)

My ffmpeg version:

```
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libtheora --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-videotoolbox --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-version3 --enable-libsmbclient --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

*Operating system and version:*
macOS 10.14.3 (Mojave)

*Handbrake log:*   https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zsn7b2agwwyu1x/Spore%20-%20Assymetrical%20Creatures%2C%20Excerpt%201%202019-04-29%2014-44-28.txt?dl=0

*CLI ffmpeg log:*   https://www.dropbox.com/s/qx2wf1h5svbrjbc/Spore%20-%20Assymetrical%20Creatures%2C%20Excerpt%201%20-%20ffmpeg%20cli.txt?dl=0

*Output from Console.app*, which occurred at the point when I tried to insert the ffmpeg version of the video, filtered by "keynote":   https://www.dropbox.com/s/2oam7cp3az9kp34/Console-keynote-output.txt?dl=0

Here are the logs of ffmpeg when I run `ffmpeg -i ...` 
on the video that was output by ffmpeg, and for the video output by Handbrake (as suggested by Gyan):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kddpit4sbq8vdhp/log_on_ffmpeg_result.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8n1ihgsp4tdwvp/log_on_handbrake_result.txt?dl=0

Any hints, suggestions , or insights will be highly appreciated.

Best regards, Gabriel

Comment: Share the full log of `ffmpeg -i ffmpeg-output` and `ffmpeg -i hb-output`

Comment: You can find it at the URL provided above (CLI ffmpeg log), it's very lengthy.

Comment: Don't see it. I don't mean the conversion logs.

Comment: Sorry , I misunderstood.  The logs are up now, see ne links in my original - now edited - post.